# remove space from in between words and replace with '+'

Tags: iphone, nsstring

```
NSString *locations=[[NSString alloc] init];
    locations=[mainView getLocationText];
    NSMutableArray *cs=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[locations componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
    NSString *city=[[cs objectAtIndex:0] replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0,[[cs objectAtIndex:0] length])];
    NSString *state=[[cs objectAtIndex:1] replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0,[[cs objectAtIndex:0] length])];
    NSMutableString *otherParams = [[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"city=%@&state=%@&beds=%@&baths=%@&minprice=%@&maxprice=%@&searchType=%@&page=1",city,state,bedsVal,bathsVal,minPriceVal,maxPriceVal,propTypeVal] autorelease];
```

It gives the error:

> Attempt to mutate immutable object
>   with
>   replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:'

And spaces are not replaced with '+'

Answer (score 3):

**My Initial answer was incorrect**, you should (as per Jasarien's answer) use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range`.
rather than `replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range`

Comment: This is irrelevant - the questioner is creating a mutable array by using `[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray];`. Passing an immutable array to this method returns a new mutable array with the contents of the passed in array.

Comment: +1 Jasarien, you are right - i got that one wrong didn't I :) i have changed my answer accordingly to reflect your correct answer

Answer (score 2):

`NSString` is immutable. `replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:` is only available on `NSMutableString`.

The method you should be using is:

`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:`

This is implemented on immutable strings, i.e `NSString` and will return a new string with the replacements you specify.